# Partitioning BigQuery table based on nested column

Tags: google-bigquery, data-partitioning

I am trying to partition a BigQuery table based on a timestamp but the column I want to use for partitioning is a nested column and has a parent record. For instance: `transaction.timestamp`.

I would like to pass the column name as `String` to a java method. How can I define this column name as `String` in java when I pass it as a parameter?

I have previously tried partitioning with non-nested columns and it worked fine. Following piece of code does not recognize the column name and results in error:

```
String columnName = "transaction.timestamp";
```

I would appreciate your help in figuring this problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For partitioning and clustering: You will need to unnest the column and have it as a first level column.

From the docs:

> The partitioning column must be a top-level field. You cannot use a leaf field from a RECORD (STRUCT) as the partitioning column.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions